# Docker images version change do not trigger terraform container update

Tags: azure, docker, docker-registry, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-instances

I'm using terraform to create container on Azure using `azure_container_group`. My container is based on a docker image stored on a private registry. When I update this image by pushing a new version with the `latest` tag my docker image have a new SHA256 ... but terraform seems not able to trigger this update.
Am i missing something ?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it. It's not difficult.

Comment: related?: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/9322

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Azure Container Instance does not have the feature that automatically updates the images. So you need to update the images yourself manually. And Terraform is just a tool to create the Azure Container Instance, you can use it to create a trigger to update the images, but you cannot use Terraform itself to do it.

To automatically update the images, I recommend you use the Azure Container Registry, it provides the trigger on the commit to update the images. Take a look at [Automate container image builds in the cloud when you commit source code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tutorial-build-task).